# Render objects from a list using map not working

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to redux. 
I'm trying to render a list that I get from props.In my List component I do this:

```
props.books.clickState.map(book=> {
            return (
                  <li key={book.id}>
                    <Book{...book} />
                  </li>
            );
        })}
```

My Book component:

```
const Book= ({ id, title, author, dispatch }) => (
<div>
    <Link to={`/books/${id}`}>
        <h4>{title}</h4>
    </Link>
    <p>Author: {author}</p>
</div>);
```

I always get an empty list. `<ul> </ul>` 
It was working yesterday and I did not change anything. 
I know that props.books.clickState is an array from  `console.log(props.books.clickState)`

[EDIT]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Book= ({ id, title, author, dispatch }) => (
    <div>
        <Link to={`/books/${id}`}>
            <h4>{title}</h4>
        </Link>
        <p>Author: {author}</p>
    </div>
);

export default connect()(Book);
```

DashBoard:

```
import React from 'react';
import BookList from './BookList ';

const DashBoard = () => (
    <div className='container__list'>
        <BookList />
    </div>
);

export default DashBoard;
```

BookList:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Book from './Book';



const BookList= (props) => (
    <div>
        Book List:
        <ul>
            { console.log(props.books) && Array.isArray(props.books) && props.books.map(book => {
                return (
                      <li key={book.id}>
                        <Book {...book} />
                      </li>
                );
            })}
        </ul>

    </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        books: state.clickState
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you receive any error and what is the value of clickState

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri No error. The value of console.log(props.books.clickState) is an Array. Each element of it has the same format as the Book Component.

Comment: Are you returning your `map` function?

Comment: Yes I am @Colin. I really have no idea what is happening here.. Can async http request and render leads to this? I think that is not the problem because I'm printing the result of books before the map function

Comment: Can you please post more code? There's not enough there to diagnose properly.

Comment: I've uploaded the code @Colin. I didn't upload reducers and actions but i'm pretty sure that they are right. The strangest thing here is that this already worked

Comment: Is the list component you refer to in your original question the `BookList`? In that render function you're returning `props.books.map` and not `props.books.clickState.map`?

Comment: could you show `console.log(props.books)` ?

Comment: Yes  It's the same ... I just changed mapStateToProps from books: state to books:state.clickState. 
console.log(props.books) returns :  [{id: 11, title: " book1", author:"author1"},{id:12, title:"book2",author:"author2"}]

Comment: Remove `console.log(props.books) && `

Comment: it worked :O Do you have a reason for that? @SafiNettah

Comment: Console.log return undefined

Comment: Thanks!! I lost so many time with this ..

Comment: @SafiNettah I was thinking that, good catch!